# Xubuntu not shutting down

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, shutdown, reboot

I'm very new to the world of Linux and I encountered some Problem. The most important/annoying one is that the PC isn't shutting down. As soon as I click "Shut Down" in Xubuntu all the programs close and I get to the boot/shut down animated screen. After a few second this screen freezes and I have to hold to power button of my laptop to... well shut it down.

My Laptop is an Acer Aspire E15-512

I think I used: Xubuntu 17.04, Zesty Zapus (but I am not sure and don't know how to check my version)

I am sure that you need more information but I don't know all the nice commands to see specific informations so it would be nice if you can tell me commands that can help me solve this problem.

Comment: it's unlikely I can help, but I'd suggest trying to shutdown from terminal. if box is running; logoff. switch to terminal with <CTRL><ALT><F4> (can be a number of function keys; I use 4) then login with username/password.  enter the command `sudo shutdown -h now`  where sudo raises privileges allowing shutdown; -h tells machine to halt-power after OS shutdown & now is the time to shutdown; ie. do it now.

Comment: Also try `sudo init 0` or `sudo poweroff` from the console.

Comment: The option where I log off and switch to the terminal and use sudo shutdown -h actually worked. Is there a way to basically just let that command run if I click the shutdown button in xubuntu?